# Click on bar in bar chart to return a data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with three columns: a name, a numerical categorical value and string.

For example:

```
Kate 8        Arizona
Alex 9        Washington
Charlene -0.3 Miami
Terry -0.3    Texas
Bill -0.3     Texas
```

I want to build a histogram of this data. However crucially, I want the histogram to be interactive so that when I click on a column in the histogram, it will return a dataframe with just the data making up that column (because I want to subsequently make a more in-depth visualisation of the data in that column).

I wrote this start of a script:

```
dict_name = {'name': ['kate', 'alex', 'charlene', 'terry', 'bill'], 'score': [8, 9, -0.3, -0.3, -0.3], 'area': ['arizona', 'washington', 'miami', 'texas', 'texas']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_name,orient='columns')
print(df)
df.hist(bins=4)
```

And it outputs a histogram of sorts:

[image]

I think I could work on the formatting of the histogram myself, but I'm wondering could someone show me how in python I could click on a bar in the bar chart, and it would print the data frame making up that bar?

Comment: Any specific libraries that you're trying to use here? What does the expected output look like?

Comment: Matplotlib's click API is documented here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html

Comment: Luke, i can use either matplotlib or seaborn. @Joooeey, would you be able to pinpoint for me where in that doc I can click a histogram bar and generate a dataframe from it? I can see/have tested where you can hover and get the value you're hovering over etc, it's the extra step of clicking and returning a data frame that I'm struggling with. Also just related, is there a magic command I should use in jupyterlab to get it to work, can hover over points in a python script, but not in jupyter? Thanks.

Comment: sorry also @Luke, so the output should just be a data frame of the information that is in that bar of the histogram, because then I'll make another different type of graphic with just that data. And then I don't have a specific library in mind because I'm not an expert in any of them, but I'm aware of matplotlib or seaborn. I can see the API doc as Joooeey kindly provided, it's just actually moving past just hovering over points and returning a value in a scatterpoint (which I can do) to actually clicking a bar and returning a data frame, in python, that i'm stuck on thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked from an [example from the Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html#simple-picking-example).

Here you go:

```
dict_name = {
    'name': ['kate', 'alex', 'charlene', 'terry', 'bill'],
    'score': [8, 9, -0.3, -0.3, -0.3],
    'area': ['arizona', 'washington', 'miami', 'texas', 'texas']
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_name, orient='columns')
print(df)
axs = df.hist(bins=4, picker=True)
ax = axs[0, 0]

def onpick(event):
    bar = event.artist
    left = bar.get_x()
    right = left + bar.get_width()
    col_df = df[(df.score >= left) & (df.score <= right)]
    print(col_df)
    
ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

Let's break that down.

- the `picker` keyword argument in `df.hist` turns click events on.
- `ax = axs[0, 0]` extracts the `Axes` object from the two-dimensional array with only one `Axes` element that `pandas` returns.
- `onpick` is the function to be executed when a bar is clicked.
- In the last line this `onpick` function is connected to the drawing canvas.
- The `'pick_event'` (in this case `onpick` but that's just the name I gave it) takes the `event` argument. This argument represents the data of the click event.
- To get the geometry from the `event`, you always need to access its `artist` property.
- Not shown: to figure out the next lines I debugged the `event` object (e.g. by printing). I saw that `event.artist` is a `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`. So apparently that represents the bar. So I called it `bar`. To find out how to get the coordinates I inspected `dir(bar)` and figured out that I can get at the left boundary with `bar.get_x()` and at the width with `bar.get_width`.
- From the above I can calculate the `left` and `right` boundaries of the bar.
- The next line does an element-wise AND of the two arrays to extract the part of the Dataframe corresponding to the bar. Caveat: I'm not sure if you need `>=` or `>`.
- Inside `onpick` you can do whatever you want with `col_df`. In this example I just print it.

That's it.